# Calling class/static method and assigning to an instance variable

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a class/static method within a class. I need SignInForm to have the defined instance variables, as they are rendered by Django's template. How does one call a method within a class from an instance variable? My objective is to update each variable with the custom widget for creating a consistent style.

```
class SignInForm(forms.Form):

    @classmethod
    def get_text_input_with_attributes():
        return forms.TextInput(attrs= {'class':'form-style'})

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    first_name.widget = SignInForm.get_text_input_with_attributes()
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50,error_messages={'required': ''})
    last_name.widget = SignInForm.get_text_input_with_attributes()
    ....lots of other custom fields
```

Error:

> name 'SignInForm' is not defined

Comment: This isn't your problem, but it is _a_ problem, and a pretty big one: That class method can _never_ be called, because it's missing the `cls` parameter.

Comment: Also, "How does one call a method within a class from an instance variable?" betrays a major misunderstanding: `first_name.widget` is _not_ an instance variable, it's a _class_ variable. Instance variables are created when the instance is created, which is long after the class exists and can be referred to, so this problem wouldn't arise in the first place.

Comment: @abarnet I'm not sure that's true.  `first_name` is an instance of the `forms.CharField` class.  Therefore, wouldn't setting `first_name.widget` be setting an instance variable?

Comment: You should consider editing your title.  The question of scoping inside of a class definition seems secondary to the real question of how to set a default widget on a django form field.

Comment: @DavidSanders: Well, yes, `widget` is an instance attribute of `first_name`, but `first_name` is a class attribute of `SignInForm`. You're right, the way I put that wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the short version:

You can't call methods of a class—even classmethods and staticmethods—while you're in the middle of defining that class, at least not easily.

So, what *can* you do? Well, really, you don't want a class method *or* a static method here. You want a regular old function. Like this:

```
class Spam(object):
    def _func():
        return 42

    class_attr = _func()

    del _func
```

After the class is defined, `_func` would be an instance method—and an un-callable instance method, since it doesn't take a `self`. (That's why I prefixed it with an underscore, and also `del`'d it, to make it harder to accidentally call it later…)

But *while* it's being defined, it's a normal function, and can be called as such.

---

I should mention that usually, wanting to do this is a sign that there's something off about your design, and the thing you're trying to write as a classmethod or staticmethod should actually be a method of a base class, or a free function or a class constructor, or maybe even a metaclass method.

As [David Sanders' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26518763/908494) explains, the specific thing you're trying to do is common enough that there's an idiomatic way to write it: as a class constructor for a `TextField` subclass.

---

How does this work?

Clearly, while you're in the middle of executing the `Spam` class definition, there is nothing called `Spam`, so you definitely can't call `Spam._func`.

But why can you call `_func`? You have to understand how class definitions are executed. Oversimplifying a bit: Python creates an empty global dictionary, runs all the code inside the `class` definition as if it were a script, then it goes back to the real globals and runs `Spam = type('Spam', (object,), that_global_dict)`. So when we do `class_attr = _func()`, we're inside that temporary global environment, and `_func` is a function in that environment, so we can call it.

So, why can't we do this with a `classmethod` or `staticmethod`?

For one thing, you need a `cls` object to call a `classmethod`, and we don't have one.

For another, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` objects aren't callable. Function objects are callable as themselves, and they're also [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html) that can be used to construct bound methods. Class and static methods are not callable, they're just descriptors that can be used to construct bound methods in special ways (bound to a class or to nothing, instead of to an instance).

---

So, what if you wanted to write something that was usable as a class-definition-time function, and also as a static method later? The simplest way is:

```
class Spam(object):
    def _func():
        return 42
    smeth = staticmethod(_func)

    class_attr = func()

    del _func
```

A decorator like `@staticmethod` just does, in effect, `_func = staticmethod(_func)`. We can do the same thing, but give the result a different name, and now we've got a static method, while still having the original function to call directly.

Comment: Even with using a @staticmethod, I get the object is not callable.

Comment: @Rich: Oh, right, you can't call static methods directly, at least not in 2.x… let me edit the answer.

Comment: @Rich: OK, I think my answer now shows how to do what (I think) you want, and also explains the concepts behind it (without going into _all_ the gory details of how class definitions and descriptors work, but there's a link if you want the gory details).

Answer (score 1):

While abernet's answer does a good job of explaining why you were getting that error, the idiomatic way to do this with django would be something like this:

```
from django import forms


class SignInFormCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('widget', forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-style'}))
        super(SignInFormCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class SignInForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = SignInFormCharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    last_name = SignInFormCharField(max_length=50, error_messages={'required': ''})
    # ...
```

Comment: I think you wanted to subclass `TextInput` there, not `CharField`, given the definition of his factory function.

Comment: @abarnert That's what I thought at first but, upon closer inspection, I realized that he said he wanted to set the default widget of each field.  That's what this does.

Comment: This answer shows me how to solve my django implementation objective, but I'm accepting the answer from @abarnert as it is more relevant to an answer other's may looking for when reading the initial question.